# How to change to font of a jupyter widget?

Tags: python-3.x, widget, jupyter-notebook

I am programming a simple form to share on my work network from my Jupyter server. In this form I have a text area like this:

```
result_area = widgets.Textarea(value='',
                               placeholder='',
                               description='Result: ',
                               disabled=False,
                               layout=Layout(display='flex', 
                                             flex_flow='column', 
                                             width='500px', 
                                             height='600px'))
display(result_area)
```

I would like to set the font of this widget to monospaced, but... but! I am not finding any option in the jupyter's documentation. Do you know any way to accomplish this?

Best regards!

Comment: I had basically the same question and someone answered it. But apparently my question got deleted. At least I cannot find it anymore.